# Making all combinations of a polyfill bundle

Tags: webpack

I want to detect features on the browser and then load a specific chunk with the exact polyfills I need. For example, assuming there are two polyfills (lets call them a and b), I would need three bundles created:

1. polyfillbundle1.js - only contains a
2. polyfillbundle2.js - only contains b
3. polyfillbundle3.js - contains both a and b

The idea would be then to load the exact polyfillbundle based on what Modernizr has detected on the browser. For example, if browser 1 does not any polyfills, browser 2 needs module b and browser 3 needs everything, then browser 2 would get polyfillbundle2.js and browser 3 would get polyfillbundle3.js

Is there a plugin for doing this? If not, how would I go about doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

One, naive way to achieve this would be to write entry configuration like this:

```
entry: {
    bundle1: "./bundle1",
    bundle2: "./bundle2",
    bundle3: "./bundle3",
},
```

Then at each entry file you would require the polyfills you want for each bundle.

I assume the next step would be to generate this configuration and the bundles dynamically (generate permutations etc.) but I think the above could serve as a starting point.

It's not enough just to generate these bundles but you'll need some smart way to make the browser load the right one...

Note that there are services such as [polyfills.io](http://polyfills.io/) that solve a lot of this for you. Depending on your case this might be one way to go. Alternatively you could just generate the worst case bundle (shims are quite small) and serve that for each user.